# Conditional matching of two lists with multi-column data.frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of data.frames with multiple columns in each of the data.frames. Each data.frame has the same structure.
In addition I have another list with multiple data.frames.

Let’s say these are the two lists:

```
firstlist <- list(a=data.frame(AA=5:1,
                        BB=1:5),
           b=data.frame(AA=5:1,
                        BB=1:5),
           c=data.frame(AA=5:1,
                        BB=1:5))
secondlist <- list(a=data.frame(AA=1:10,
                        BB=c(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0)),
           b=data.frame(AA=1:10,
                        BB=c(0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)),
           c=data.frame(AA=1:10,
                        BB=c(1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0)))
```

Now I want to add column CC to all data.frames in firstlist and fill them accordingly to the values in column BB from the secondlist.

The problem is: I need to check if the row in AA or BB from firstlist contains the value from AA in secondlist and fill the new column CC in firstlist with the value from BB in secondlist.

The expected result with the example data above would be:

```
> firstlist
$a
     AA BB CC
  1  5  1  0
  2  4  2  0
  3  3  3  1
  4  2  4  0
  5  1  5  0

$b
    AA BB CC
  1  5  1  0
  2  4  2  1
  3  3  3  0
  4  2  4  1
  5  1  5  0

$c
    AA BB CC
  1  5  1  1
  2  4  2  0
  3  3  3  0
  4  2  4  0
  5  1  5  1
```

Do I need to use a For loop or is there any other way?

UPDATE:
See [Thell's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17201471/2123407) for boolen data and [eddie's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17199228/2123407) for all datatypes.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: could you show us the expected result for your data? The first part is a bit unclear to me... "I need to check if the row in AA or BB from firstlist..."

Comment: @Arun I have edited the question. Added the expected result. 
In other words:
I need to check if any row in column AA or BB in every data.frame of firstlist contains the same value as a row in column AA in the same named data.frame of secondlist. If so, I need to fill the new column CC in firstlist with the according value from BB in secondlist. It sounds more compliated as it is but I don't know how to describe it in a better way.

Comment: how is $b column `CC` `0,1,0,1,0`? Could you explain please?

Comment: I have problems to fromat the code in the comment.
It is because in secondlist $b the column BB is 1 at 2 and 7. 
In firstlist there is a 2 in row 2 BB and row 4 AA.

Comment: Okay, you seem to have changed the data and I was working on the old data (it seems so). Now I get it.

Comment: Yes, I changed the data in the example as I wanted to simulate some more matches.

Comment: it's alright. I've answered, in case you're interested.

Comment: Is CC truly TRUE/FALSE or that that just a case of the example?

Comment: Yes, it is boolen indeed. Thanks for your addition!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If CC is truly boolean...

```
f <- function(a,b) cbind( a, CC=b$BB[ match( a$AA, b$AA ) ] |
                                b$BB[ match( a$BB, b$AA ) ]   )
mapply( f, firstlist, secondlist, SIMPLIFY=F )
```

Straight-forward, quick, and keeps names...

benchmark of example vs lapply version::

```
Unit: milliseconds
          expr       min       lq   median       uq      max neval
   this mapply  1.726471 1.840671 1.870504 1.939473 13.88875   100
 Arun's lapply  2.930061 3.048110 3.134402 3.209786 14.61630   100
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another relatively shorter way (Assuming `BB` in `secondlist` is binary (has only 0 and another value):

```
lapply(seq_along(firstlist), function(ix) {
    tt <- secondlist[[ix]][secondlist[[ix]]$BB != 0, ]
    transform(firstlist[[ix]], CC = 1 * (firstlist[[ix]]$AA %in% tt$AA | 
        firstlist[[ix]]$BB %in% tt$AA))
})
```

Comment: Thank you! As it's binary it works very well. Just one cosmetic question: Is there a way to preserve the 'names' of 'firstlist'? I can restore them as they are also stored in an extra vector but it would be nice to preserve them.

Comment: you can wrap the `lapply` with `setNames()` like: `out <- setNames(lapply(...), names(firstlist))`

Answer (score 1):

```
lapply(seq_along(firstlist),
       function(i) {
         d.1 = merge(firstlist[[i]], secondlist[[i]], by = "AA", sort = FALSE)
         names(d.1) = c("AA", "BB", "CC")
         d.2 = suppressWarnings(merge(firstlist[[i]], secondlist[[i]], by.x = "BB", by.y = "AA", sort = FALSE))
         names(d.2) = c("BB", "AA", "CC")
         d.1$CC = 0 + (d.1$CC | d.2$CC)
         d.1
       })
```

You may want to rename the columns above instead of suppressing the warnings.

Comment: I think is more complex than this one because you don't duplicate entry for those who matches with BB column in first list.

Comment: Yes, this code does not take into account BB form firstlist.
It also not preserves the names of the data.frames and columns.
But it might be a good way to start.

Comment: @eddi Awesome! It does what I wanted with the example. I'll try to apply this to the actual data and will report as soon as done.

Comment: @eddi Your code works very well but I was not able to adapt it to my actual data. This is the reason why I accepted the other answer.