# Conditional multi column matching (reviewed with new example)

Tags: python, pandas, matching

I tried to rework my question in order to match the quality criteria and spent more time in trying to achieve the result on my own.

Given are two DataFrames

```
a = DataFrame({"id" : ["id1"] * 3 + ["id2"] * 3 + ["id3"] * 3,
               "left" : [6, 2, 5, 2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 4],
               "right" : [1, 3, 4, 6, 5, 3, 6, 3, 2]               
             })

b = DataFrame({"id" : ["id1"] * 6 + ["id2"] * 6 + ["id3"] * 6,
               "left_and_right" : range(1,7) * 3,  
               "boolen" : [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 , 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
             })
```

The expected result is

```
result = DataFrame({"id" : ["id1"] * 3 + ["id2"] * 3 + ["id3"] * 3,
                    "left"  : [6, 2, 5, 2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 4],
                    "right"  : [1, 3, 4, 6, 5, 3, 6, 3, 2],
                    "NEW": [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]               
                  })
```

So I want to check in each row of DataFrame b if there is a row in DataFrame a where a.id == b.id AND then look up if b.left_and_right is in (==) a.left OR a.rigtht. 
 If such a row is found and b.boolen is True/1 for either the value of a.left or a.right, the value of a.NEW in this row should be also True/1. 
I hope the example illustrates it better than my words.

To sum it up: I want to look up if in each row where id is the same for both DataFrames whether b.boolen is True/1 for a value in b.left_and_right and if this value is in a.left or in a.right, the new value in a.NEW should also be TRUE/1.

I have tried using the pd.match() and pd.merge() function in combination with & and | operators but could not achieve the wanted result.

Some time ago I had asked a very simillar question dealing with a simillar problem in R (data was organized in a slightly other way, so it was a bit different) but now I fail using the same approach in python. 
Related question: [Conditional matching of two lists with multi-column data.frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198817/conditional-matching-of-two-lists-with-multi-column-data-frames)

Thanks

Comment: Can you spell this out a bit more: `"A" AND ("B" OR "C")`? Do you mean that `a.A == b.A` AND any elements common to both `a.B` and `a.C`?

Comment: Also, this is not a very descriptive example...

Comment: so for all of the rows in this example?

Comment: Yes, it should check all rows of b and find any corresponding row in a according to the matching rule.

Comment: @Andy Hayden I tried to provide a better example. Please let me know how I could further improve my question.

Comment: that looks like a better example, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a boolean masks with & (and) and | (or):

```
In [11]: (a.A == b.A) & ((a.B == b.E) | (a.C == b.E)) # they all satisfy this requirement!
Out[11]: 
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
dtype: bool

In [12]: b.D[(a.A == b.A) & ((a.B == b.E) | (a.C == b.E))]
Out[12]: 
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    0
Name: D, dtype: int64

In [13]: a['NEW'] = b.D[(a.A == b.A) & ((a.B == b.E) | (a.C == b.E))]

In [14]: a
Out[14]: 
     A  B  C  NEW
0  foo  1  4    0
1  goo  2  3    1
2  doo  3  1    0
3  boo  4  2    0
```

Update with the slightly different question:

```
In [21]: merged = pd.merge(a, b, on='id')

In [22]: matching = merged[(merged.left == merged.left_and_right) | (merged.right == merged.left_and_right)]

In [23]: (matching.groupby(['id', 'left', 'right'])['boolen'].sum()).reset_index()
Out[23]: 
    id  left  right  boolen
0  id1     2      3       1
1  id1     5      4       1
2  id1     6      1       0
3  id2     1      5       2
4  id2     2      6       0
5  id2     4      3       1
6  id3     2      3       1
7  id3     4      2       0
8  id3     5      6       1
```

Note there is a 2 here, so perhaps you want to care about those > 0.

```
In [24]: (matching.groupby(['id', 'left', 'right'])['boolen'].sum() > 0).reset_index()
Out[24]: 
    id  left  right boolen
0  id1     2      3   True
1  id1     5      4   True
2  id1     6      1  False
3  id2     1      5   True
4  id2     2      6  False
5  id2     4      3   True
6  id3     2      3   True
7  id3     4      2  False
8  id3     5      6   True
```

*You may want to rename the boolen column to NEW.*

Comment: @PhillipCloud I wrote this earlier (in case this was the answer). Also, TOTD. :p

Comment: @Andy Hayden This one won't work as the real data is not of the same length. "ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare" I really have to admit that the example provided does not fully reflect the problem. I will try to rework it.

Comment: @Nikita If your `Series` objects are not in a `DataFrame`, then why did you provide them in one in your example?

Comment: @PhillipCloud I think we can all agree this is a *terrible* example. It's unclear to me what OP wants == to mean in this context...

Comment: @Phillip Cloud The Series objects are in DataFrames. They are not of the same length.
I'm really sorry for the confusing example. It's not an excuse but it was really late yesterday... Will rework it as soon as I can. For now I'll try to explain it in words. I have two DataFrames with 3 columns each. They are of different length.
I just want to check for each row in DataFrame b if the value in b.A can be found in any row of a.A and then in addition check if b.E is in a.B or in a.C of the same row. If so the value of b.D should be copied to a new column in the row where the values matched.